# GoogleAPI doesn't accept Python boolean value

Tags: python, google-api, ttn

We are interacting with the [public TTN API](https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/reference/) (based on Google API) and I am trying to deliver a boolean value. This would be my data package:

```
ns_data = {
    "end_device": {
        "ids": {
            "dev_eui": str(self.device.internal_id),
            "join_eui": str(self.device.app_eui)
        },
        "supports_join": True
    }, "field_mask": {
        "paths": [
            "supports_join"
        ]
}}
request("PUT", f"/api/v3/ns/applications/{str(self.device.company.uuid)}/devices/{self.device.uuid}", json=ns_data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + API_KEY})
```

The response is `{"code":3,"message":"error:pkg/networkserver:field_value (invalid value of field 'supports_join')","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/ttn.lorawan.v3.ErrorDetails","namespace":"pkg/networkserver","name":"field_value","message_format":"invalid value of field {field}","attributes":{"field":"supports_join"}`.

When changing the field to string and providing `'true'` here the error changes slightly to `{"code":3,"message":"ReadBool: expect t or f, but found \\", error found in #10 byte of ...|s_join\\": \\"true\\"}, \\"f (...)` which is even more strange. I tried providing it as a dict as well, but the [API definition states that it should be bool](https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/reference/api/end_device/#message:EndDevice).

Comment: duid you tried "supports_join": 1?

Comment: Yes I did, but as the `json.dumps` in `request.request` converts it to json 'true' the same error appears. @Fribu-SmartSolutions